# Ubuntu searching active directory users

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba

I followed [these instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-9.04-samba-server-integrated-with-active-directory) the other day to set up a Samba share with AD authentication on Ubuntu.

It worked fine, but now, whenever I do some kind of operation with users or groups, the system slows to a crawl and seems to lock up (web server won't respond, for example).

The only thing I can thing of is that when I tab part of a user/groupname, it's searching the entire AD (which is quite large) for matches. Is this what's happening? If it is, is there any way I can stop this? If not, what's going on? The only major change I made was just following the instructions linked to above.

Comment: Are you running nscd and is it appropriately configured?

Comment: No, I am not running nscd. I'm guessing I should be?

Comment: It will cache your uid/gids locally which will reduce the load on that remote server. This doesn't necessarily completely resolve your problem though in the sense that maybe there is something unnecessary going on in the first place. I just throw this out because the symptoms that you are experiencing might be alleviated by nscd, which is very easy to install and configure.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off `winbind enum users` and `winbind enum groups` to keep winbind from displaying AD users/groups in these sorts of situations.